# Is it possible to assign style/css to one element based on another element?

Tags: html, css

I have a 3d party library (fullcalendar) that dynamically assigns height of the elements based on some internal calculations to look nice in any viewport:

```
<div style="height: 72px;">
```

However this does not happen for all the elements, some have fixed height. I don't want to change the code of the 3d party library and was thinking if it's maybe possible to somehow "apply" one element's style to another using css. Something like:

```
.myDiv {
   height: anotherDiv.height
}
```

Perhaps there are some other ways of getting the same outcome, but I cannot think of any.

Comment: With JavaScript sure. With plain vanilla CSS no.

Comment: I don't think it is possible with pure CSS, until the element is nested.

Comment: does this other div has a known height, an id, or a class ? is that div within a specific place in its container, then CSS should be able to do so by adding a class aside the class of that div or using a more specific selector to target that single div. else, you need javascript to retrieve height needed and apply it to this specific div ... might be unclear but your question doesn't tell enough to give a positive or négative answer ... it depends on structure you have, ids , class and your style sheet . we can just fairly answer : it depends :) or go on some personnal opinion or guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if you are looking for a solution with `Javascript` (I do not know if it is possible only with `CSS` but I do not think so) but here is an approach using it:

If you have two divs with two different IDs:

```
<div id="div1" style="height: 72px;"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Then you can read the style property of the first one using [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle):

```
var element = document.getElementById('div1'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    height1 = style.getPropertyValue('height');
```

And setting it to the second one:

```
var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
div2.style.height = height1;
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3yyksz17/) to see how it works.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I was trying to do it without javascript, since the height of a 3d party component does change during resize e.g. Perhaps there is no other way though...

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik Maybe you can wrap the code I have put above in a function and call them in the onresize method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize

Comment: Thanks for help, I will try to do that

Answer (score 0):

By Using Less Its Possible  see example

```
.rounded_corners {
      -moz-border-radius: 8px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
      border-radius: 8px;
    }

    #header {
      .rounded_corners;
    }

    #footer {
      .rounded_corners;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are in the same container, you can use a **[flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**.

```css
#container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items:stretch /* That line gives them the same height */
    }

#container > * {
  background:gray;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
      <div>
        Some<br>very<br>high<br>text<br>that<br>uses<br>disgusting<br>BRs
      </div>
      <div>
        The short one
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi they are not directly under the same container (only have the same distant parent), so I guess this will not work then?

Comment: Thanks for help anyway :)